# Using Microsoft Graph API refresh token with Delphi OAuth2

Tags: api, delphi, graph, oauth-2.0

I am pretty new to OAuth2 and all of the REST components in Delphi (using 10.3 Rio).

My intention is to access the Microsoft Rest API via the Delphi REST components.

For testing, I dropped the RESTClient, RESTRequest, RESTResponse, and OAuth2 components on a Form, and entered the Application ID and Endpoint URLs in the OAuth2 interface.

[image: Oauth Interface Image]

When I hit "authorize", the Office 365 window pops up and wants me to log in.

Is there a chance to get around this popup, so that the login is executed automatically?

The access_token expires after an hour or so, and I need to refresh it using the refresh_token.

How can I do this with the OAuth2 component?

Comment: By design, OAuth lets the user authenticate via a web page and give authorization to the client application to perform some action. The application never knows the login/password. So the process can't be automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my sample project

https://github.com/geoffsmith82/GmailAuthSMTP

It has a Microsoft login option.  Basically you need to send offline_access as a requested scope and then save the returned refresh token for later use.  When you want to later login, you make a authentication request using the saved refresh_token to get a usable access_token.  The first time you login you will need to login via the web browser still though.